# ros launch problem

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As I have just started learning Ros with the help of Ros tutorials the problem which i am facing is that according to Ros tutorials link http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRxconsoleRoslaunch when i type roslaunch command in the new terminal it gives me an error that danishraza@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace$ roscd beginner_tutorials roscd: No such package 'beginner_tutorials'

I have Ubuntu 10.04 Lts on my machine and Ros electric.And have already created package beginner_tutorials .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28174/ros-launch-problem/) by [danish](https://answers.ros.org/users/1766/danish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-22**:
Have you properly configured your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you probably need to set up your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, type the following in your terminal:

export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace/:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2012-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3